InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Guid' to type 'System.String' on dbContext.Database.MigrateAsync()
In my application I have an Entity Framework setup, with authentication using EF's Identity. I've chosen to have the Id properties for all my entities set to type Guid.
When trying to apply migrations to the database to a Microsoft SqlServer from code I ran into the error below (applying the migration to Sqlite works without issues):
System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Guid' to type 'System.String'.
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Storage.Internal.SqlServerStringTypeMapping.GenerateNonNullSqlLiteral(Object value)
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalTypeMapping.GenerateProviderValueSqlLiteral(Object value)
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.UpdateSqlGenerator.AppendSqlLiteral(StringBuilder commandStringBuilder, IColumnModification modification, String tableName, String schema)
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.UpdateSqlGenerator.<>c.<AppendValues>b__24_0(StringBuilder sb, IColumnModification o, ValueTuple`3 p)
         at System.Text.StringBuilderExtensions.AppendJoin[T,TParam](StringBuilder stringBuilder, IEnumerable`1 values, TParam param, Action`3 joinAction, String separator)
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.UpdateSqlGenerator.AppendValues(StringBuilder commandStringBuilder, String name, String schema, IReadOnlyList`1 operations)
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Update.Internal.SqlServerUpdateSqlGenerator.AppendInsertMultipleRows(StringBuilder commandStringBuilder, IReadOnlyList`1 modificationCommands, List`1 writeOperations, Boolean& requiresTransaction)
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Update.Internal.SqlServerUpdateSqlGenerator.AppendBulkInsertOperation(StringBuilder commandStringBuilder, IReadOnlyList`1 modificationCommands, Int32 commandPosition, Boolean& requiresTransaction)
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Update.Internal.SqlServerModificationCommandBatch.ApplyPendingBulkInsertCommands()
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Update.Internal.SqlServerModificationCommandBatch.Complete(Boolean moreBatchesExpected)
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.Internal.CommandBatchPreparer.CreateCommandBatches(IEnumerable`1 commandSet, Boolean moreCommandSets, Boolean assertColumnModification, ParameterNameGenerator parameterNameGenerator)+MoveNext()
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.SqlServerMigrationsSqlGenerator.Generate(InsertDataOperation operation, IModel model, MigrationCommandListBuilder builder, Boolean terminate)
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.MigrationsSqlGenerator.<>c.<.cctor>b__82_28(MigrationsSqlGenerator g, MigrationOperation o, IModel m, MigrationCommandListBuilder b)
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.MigrationsSqlGenerator.Generate(MigrationOperation operation, IModel model, MigrationCommandListBuilder builder)
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.SqlServerMigrationsSqlGenerator.Generate(MigrationOperation operation, IModel model, MigrationCommandListBuilder builder)
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.MigrationsSqlGenerator.Generate(IReadOnlyList`1 operations, IModel model, MigrationsSqlGenerationOptions options)
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.SqlServerMigrationsSqlGenerator.Generate(IReadOnlyList`1 operations, IModel model, MigrationsSqlGenerationOptions options)
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.Migrator.GenerateUpSql(Migration migration, MigrationsSqlGenerationOptions options)
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.Migrator.<>c__DisplayClass16_2.<GetMigrationCommandLists>b__2()
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.Migrator.MigrateAsync(String targetMigration, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at RonBv.GameSite.Api.Data.DatabaseMigrator.ApplyMigrations(WebApplication app) in D:\a\1\s\...\Data\DatabaseMigrator.cs:line 25

This seems to indicate that during the 'Up' process, the conversion error occurs on my migration, but I can't seem to figure out what the exact cause for this is.
Line 25 of the DatabaseMigrator class is the following:
await dbContext.Database.MigrateAsync(cancellationTokenSource.Token);

The only migration I have is the one below:
namespace RonBv.GameSite.Api.Data.Migrations
{
    /// <inheritdoc />
    public partial class Initial : Migration
    {
        /// <inheritdoc />
        protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
        {
            migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
                name: "AspNetRoles",
                columns: table => new
                {
                    Id = table.Column<Guid>(type: "TEXT", nullable: false),
                    Name = table.Column<string>(type: "TEXT", maxLength: 256, nullable: true),
                    NormalizedName = table.Column<string>(type: "TEXT", maxLength: 256, nullable: true),
                    ConcurrencyStamp = table.Column<string>(type: "TEXT", nullable: true)
                },
                constraints: table =>
                {
                    table.PrimaryKey("PK_AspNetRoles", x => x.Id);
                });

            migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
                name: "AspNetUsers",
                columns: table => new
                {
                    Id = table.Column<Guid>(type: "TEXT", nullable: false),
                    UserName = table.Column<string>(type: "TEXT", maxLength: 256, nullable: true),
                    NormalizedUserName = table.Column<string>(type: "TEXT", maxLength: 256, nullable: true),
                    Email = table.Column<string>(type: "TEXT", maxLength: 256, nullable: true),
                    NormalizedEmail = table.Column<string>(type: "TEXT", maxLength: 256, nullable: true),
                    EmailConfirmed = table.Column<bool>(type: "INTEGER", nullable: false),
                    PasswordHash = table.Column<string>(type: "TEXT", nullable: true),
                    SecurityStamp = table.Column<string>(type: "TEXT", nullable: true),
                    ConcurrencyStamp = table.Column<string>(type: "TEXT", nullable: true),
                    PhoneNumber = table.Column<string>(type: "TEXT", nullable: true),
                    PhoneNumberConfirmed = table.Column<bool>(type: "INTEGER", nullable: false),
                    TwoFactorEnabled = table.Column<bool>(type: "INTEGER", nullable: false),
                    LockoutEnd = table.Column<DateTimeOffset>(type: "TEXT", nullable: true),
                    LockoutEnabled = table.Column<bool>(type: "INTEGER", nullable: false),
                    AccessFailedCount = table.Column<int>(type: "INTEGER", nullable: false)
                },
                constraints: table =>
                {
                    table.PrimaryKey("PK_AspNetUsers", x => x.Id);
                });

            migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
                name: "AspNetRoleClaims",
                columns: table => new
                {
                    Id = table.Column<int>(type: "INTEGER", nullable: false)
                        .Annotation("Sqlite:Autoincrement", true),
                    RoleId = table.Column<Guid>(type: "TEXT", nullable: false),
                    ClaimType = table.Column<string>(type: "TEXT", nullable: true),
                    ClaimValue = table.Column<string>(type: "TEXT", nullable: true)
                },
                constraints: table =>
                {
                    table.PrimaryKey("PK_AspNetRoleClaims", x => x.Id);
                    table.ForeignKey(
                        name: "FK_AspNetRoleClaims_AspNetRoles_RoleId",
                        column: x => x.RoleId,
                        principalTable: "AspNetRoles",
                        principalColumn: "Id",
                        onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);
                });

            migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
                name: "AspNetUserClaims",
                columns: table => new
                {
                    Id = table.Column<int>(type: "INTEGER", nullable: false)
                        .Annotation("Sqlite:Autoincrement", true),
                    UserId = table.Column<Guid>(type: "TEXT", nullable: false),
                    ClaimType = table.Column<string>(type: "TEXT", nullable: true),
                    ClaimValue = table.Column<string>(type: "TEXT", nullable: true)
                },
                constraints: table =>
                {
                    table.PrimaryKey("PK_AspNetUserClaims", x => x.Id);
                    table.ForeignKey(
                        name: "FK_AspNetUserClaims_AspNetUsers_UserId",
                        column: x => x.UserId,
                        principalTable: "AspNetUsers",
                        principalColumn: "Id",
                        onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);
                });

            migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
                name: "AspNetUserLogins",
                columns: table => new
                {
                    LoginProvider = table.Column<string>(type: "TEXT", nullable: false),
                    ProviderKey = table.Column<string>(type: "TEXT", nullable: false),
                    ProviderDisplayName = table.Column<string>(type: "TEXT", nullable: true),
                    UserId = table.Column<Guid>(type: "TEXT", nullable: false)
                },
                constraints: table =>
                {
                    table.PrimaryKey("PK_AspNetUserLogins", x => new { x.LoginProvider, x.ProviderKey });
                    table.ForeignKey(
                        name: "FK_AspNetUserLogins_AspNetUsers_UserId",
                        column: x => x.UserId,
                        principalTable: "AspNetUsers",
                        principalColumn: "Id",
                        onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);
                });

            migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
                name: "AspNetUserRoles",
                columns: table => new
                {
                    UserId = table.Column<Guid>(type: "TEXT", nullable: false),
                    RoleId = table.Column<Guid>(type: "TEXT", nullable: false)
                },
                constraints: table =>
                {
                    table.PrimaryKey("PK_AspNetUserRoles", x => new { x.UserId, x.RoleId });
                    table.ForeignKey(
                        name: "FK_AspNetUserRoles_AspNetRoles_RoleId",
                        column: x => x.RoleId,
                        principalTable: "AspNetRoles",
                        principalColumn: "Id",
                        onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);
                    table.ForeignKey(
                        name: "FK_AspNetUserRoles_AspNetUsers_UserId",
                        column: x => x.UserId,
                        principalTable: "AspNetUsers",
                        principalColumn: "Id",
                        onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);
                });

            migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
                name: "AspNetUserTokens",
                columns: table => new
                {
                    UserId = table.Column<Guid>(type: "TEXT", nullable: false),
                    LoginProvider = table.Column<string>(type: "TEXT", nullable: false),
                    Name = table.Column<string>(type: "TEXT", nullable: false),
                    Value = table.Column<string>(type: "TEXT", nullable: true)
                },
                constraints: table =>
                {
                    table.PrimaryKey("PK_AspNetUserTokens", x => new { x.UserId, x.LoginProvider, x.Name });
                    table.ForeignKey(
                        name: "FK_AspNetUserTokens_AspNetUsers_UserId",
                        column: x => x.UserId,
                        principalTable: "AspNetUsers",
                        principalColumn: "Id",
                        onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);
                });

            migrationBuilder.InsertData(
                table: "AspNetRoles",
                columns: new[] { "Id", "ConcurrencyStamp", "Name", "NormalizedName" },
                values: new object[,]
                {
                    { new Guid("501519c5-07b5-4e31-8d18-70ec8eb83010"), null, "User", "USER" },
                    { new Guid("91fb18b3-c4ca-4d05-8ff9-bbadd558475a"), null, "Administrator", "ADMINISTRATOR" }
                });

            migrationBuilder.InsertData(
                table: "AspNetUsers",
                columns: new[] { "Id", "AccessFailedCount", "ConcurrencyStamp", "Email", "EmailConfirmed", "LockoutEnabled", "LockoutEnd", "NormalizedEmail", "NormalizedUserName", "PasswordHash", "PhoneNumber", "PhoneNumberConfirmed", "SecurityStamp", "TwoFactorEnabled", "UserName" },
                values: new object[] { new Guid("ce64e55b-0cd4-4ffa-a72c-226e6859188d"), 0, "25bdd728-f300-468f-8733-41fa7ab384f6", "administrator@example.com", true, false, null, "ADMINISTRATOR@EXAMPLE.COM", "ADMINISTRATOR", "...", null, false, "", false, "Administrator" });

            migrationBuilder.InsertData(
                table: "AspNetUserRoles",
                columns: new[] { "RoleId", "UserId" },
                values: new object[] { new Guid("91fb18b3-c4ca-4d05-8ff9-bbadd558475a"), new Guid("ce64e55b-0cd4-4ffa-a72c-226e6859188d") });

            migrationBuilder.CreateIndex(
                name: "IX_AspNetRoleClaims_RoleId",
                table: "AspNetRoleClaims",
                column: "RoleId");

            migrationBuilder.CreateIndex(
                name: "RoleNameIndex",
                table: "AspNetRoles",
                column: "NormalizedName",
                unique: true);

            migrationBuilder.CreateIndex(
                name: "IX_AspNetUserClaims_UserId",
                table: "AspNetUserClaims",
                column: "UserId");

            migrationBuilder.CreateIndex(
                name: "IX_AspNetUserLogins_UserId",
                table: "AspNetUserLogins",
                column: "UserId");

            migrationBuilder.CreateIndex(
                name: "IX_AspNetUserRoles_RoleId",
                table: "AspNetUserRoles",
                column: "RoleId");

            migrationBuilder.CreateIndex(
                name: "EmailIndex",
                table: "AspNetUsers",
                column: "NormalizedEmail");

            migrationBuilder.CreateIndex(
                name: "UserNameIndex",
                table: "AspNetUsers",
                column: "NormalizedUserName",
                unique: true);
        }

        /// <inheritdoc />
        protected override void Down(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
        {
            migrationBuilder.DropTable(
                name: "AspNetRoleClaims");

            migrationBuilder.DropTable(
                name: "AspNetUserClaims");

            migrationBuilder.DropTable(
                name: "AspNetUserLogins");

            migrationBuilder.DropTable(
                name: "AspNetUserRoles");

            migrationBuilder.DropTable(
                name: "AspNetUserTokens");

            migrationBuilder.DropTable(
                name: "AspNetRoles");

            migrationBuilder.DropTable(
                name: "AspNetUsers");
        }
    }
}

I'm really hoping anybody could shed some light on why this problem occurred and what I can do to prevent it in the future.

Here... new Guid("ce64e55b-0cd4-4ffa-a72c-226e6859188d") should be  .ToString(). Guid is an object and not a string. U have to do it  .ToString() to all.

I suggest you could also try this  Id = table.Column<Guid>(type: "uniqueidentifier", nullable: false) not use the Text.

The migration you have is SQLite-specific. If you want to use migrations with different providers check Migrations with Multiple providers. By default a migration is created only for the active provider which, in your project, seems to be SQLite. To generate migrations for multiple providers you'll have to use separate migrations projects

Based on Panagiotis Kanavos' comment, I was able to find that the cause for this issue was the discrepancy between the providers I used in my development and accept environments, where I used Sqlite in my development environment, and SqlServer in my production environment. Both providers handle Guids in a different manner, and depending on what provider was selected the migrations will be generated.
My error mainly was that I picked tried to select my provider based on my environment as shown below:
builder.Services.AddDbContext<MyDbContext>(options =>
{
    if(builder.Environment.IsDevelopment()) {
        options.UseSqlite(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("SqliteConnection"));
    } else {
        options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("SqlServerConnection"));
    }
};

The problem with this was that my migrations were always generated in development, and therefore incompatible with my accept database. The solution to this is either to have the same type of database on development and accept / production, or have separate migrations for development and accept / production as described in the Microsoft documentation below:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/providers?tabs=dotnet-core-cli
